# Using jQuery to append a li makes it disappear immediately

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html

http://adamginther.com/checkify/lists-overview.html?

http://jsfiddle.net/AGinther/Ysq4a/

When input is submitted it should create a list item containing whatever was in the text field. It appears for a second on my website but on on the fiddle and doesn't append any text. I've tried creating a button tag and an a tag to fix this but I got no results.

HTML:

```
<div id="lists-overview">
        <form>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Create a list">
            <input type="submit" value="Add List" id="list-builder">
        </form>
          <ul>
              <li><a href="index.html">Item 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
          </ul>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
var createList = $('#lists-overview input[type="text"]').val();

$('#list-builder').click(function() {
    $('#lists-overview ul li:last').after('<li>Test</li>');

});
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The input button is submitting the form, hence reloading the page.
You need to overcome the default behaviour of the button by using `e.preventDefault()` or by changing the type "submit" of the button.

working example by just changing input `type='button'`

http://jsfiddle.net/Ysq4a/5/

Comment: is there a way to append the content after the page is refreshed?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [e.preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) to prevent default action which will reload the page of your `input` submit button:

```
$('#list-builder').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#lists-overview ul li:last').after('<li>Test</li>');
});
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ysq4a/6/)**

Answer (score 0):

hSubmit button is submitting the form thats the issue

prevent the default submit functionality by adding e.preventDefault(); after adding the li

```
$('#list-builder').click(function(e) {
    $('#lists-overview ul li:last').after('<li>Test</li>');
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

or simply change your button type submit to button

```
<input type="button" value="Add List" id="list-builder">
```